# CSS3 Transition jolting when applied to div containing HTML5 video?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html5-video, transition

I have a website with a setup similar to this jsfiddle the only difference really is there is a CSS3 carousel/slideshow of 4 HTML5 videos inside the main body of content.

As you can see in the fiddle the transition is smooth however in my actual website the slide down and up is really glitchy and not smooth at all.

Any ideas why this might be happening would be greatly appreciated.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9qKrB/19/)

JS

```
$(".contact-button").on('click', function(){
var clicked = $('#cont').attr('data-state');

if(clicked=='true')
{
$('#cont').attr('data-state','false');
$(".wrapper").css({"top": "100px", "-webkit-transition": "top 0.5s ease-in-out", "-
moz-transition": "top 0.5s ease-in-out", "-o-transition": "top 0.5s ease-in-out", "-moz-
transition": "top 0.5s ease-in-out", "transition": "top 0.5s ease-in-out"});
}else if(clicked=='false')
{
    $('#cont').attr('data-state','true');
    $(".wrapper").css({"top": "0px", "-webkit-transition": "top 0.5s ease-in-out", "-moz-
    transition": "top 0.5s ease-in-out", "-o-transition": "top 0.5s ease-in-out", "-ms-
    transition": "top 0.5s ease-in-out", "transition": "top 0.5s ease-in-out"});
}
});

$(".description-button").on('click', function(){
var clic = $('#des').attr('data-statee');
if(clic =='true')
{
    $('#des').attr('data-statee','false');
    $(".wrapper").css({"top": "-100px"});
}
if(clic =='false')
{
    $('#des').attr('data-statee','true');
    $(".wrapper").css({"top": "0px"});
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are animating the `top` property, which is a layout property. You shouldn't do this. I changed your CSS and your code, simplifying it to use CSS classes instead of hard-coded values in javascript, and now it uses CSS 3D transforms (where available), which are much quicker and hardware-accelerated. Now it should run smoothly.

Here is the updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9qKrB/25/).

Changes in the CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 1440px;
    margin: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
}


.wrapper.down
{
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 100px, 0px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(100px);
    -transform: translate3d(0px, 100px, 0px);
}

.wrapper.up
{
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, -100px, 0px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-100px);
    -transform: translate3d(0px, -100px, 0px);
}
```

New javascript:

```
$(".contact-button").on('click', function(){
   var clicked = $('#cont').attr('data-state');

    if(clicked=='true')
    {
        $('#cont').attr('data-state','false');
        $(".wrapper").removeClass('up').addClass('down');
    }else if(clicked=='false')
    {
        $('#cont').attr('data-state','true');
         
        $(".wrapper").removeClass('up down');
    }
});



$(".description-button").on('click', function(){
    var clic = $('#des').attr('data-statee');
    if(clic =='true')
    {
          $('#des').attr('data-statee','false');
        $(".wrapper").removeClass('down').addClass('up');
    }
    if(clic =='false')
    {
        $('#des').attr('data-statee','true');
        $(".wrapper").removeClass('down up');
    }
});
```

As you see, I've added the `up` and `down` CSS classes. Adding and removing them moves the `.wrapper` DIV.

Comment: Thanks so much for explaining this to me so clearly and also providing a working example. This worked perfectly.